# Fetch and Update Data in same page CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I got stuck in a a problem in which I need to update some info from database in the same page that is shown.

On this case I'm fetching some "global settings" from a website in an index page which comes with a form in it. Here is a picture of it just to make it more clear to understand what I mean.

[image: Built with CodeIgniter Global Settings]
[image: Built with CodeIgniter Global Settings]

As you can see I created the button and I made it possible to see the values from the database, the problem is that I can not figure it out how to update it from there. Can somebody suggest an idea?

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Settings extends Admin_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website_favicon', 'Favicon', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website_logo', 'Logon', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website_name', 'Website Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website_credits', 'Credits', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website_credits_link', 'Credits Link', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website_copyright', 'Copyright', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            // Get Current Subject
            $data['item'] = $this->Settings_model->get_website_data();
            //Load View Into Template
            $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'settings/index', $data);

        } else {

            // Create website settings
            $data = array(
                'website_favicon'   => $this->input->post('website_favicon'),
                'website_logo'      => $this->input->post('website_logo'),
                'website_name'      => $this->input->post('webiste_name'),
                'website_credits'   => $this->input->post('website_credits'),
                'website_credits_link'  => $this->input->post('website_credits_link'),
                'website_copyright' => $this->input->post('website_copyright'),
            );

            // Update User
            $this->Settings_model->update($id, $data);

            // Activity Array
            $data = array(
                'resource_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
                'type'        => 'website settings',
                'action'      => 'updated',
                'user_id'     => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'message'     => 'User (' . $data["username"] . ') updated the website settings'
            );

            // Add Activity  
            $this->Activity_model->add($data);

            //Create Message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Website setting has been updated');

            //Redirect to Users
            redirect('admin/settings');
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my model:

```
<?php

class Settings_model extends CI_MODEL
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'website_settings';
    }


    public function update($id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }


    public function get_website_data()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id', 1);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

and here is my view(index.php) with the form:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Website Settings</h2>
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('success')) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alert!</h4>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error')) : ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alert!</h4>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="alert alert-danger">'); ?>
<?php echo form_open('admin/settings/index/'.$item->id); ?>
    <!-- Website Favicon -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Website Favicon', 'title'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_favicon',
                'id'    => 'website_favicon',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_favicon
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Logo -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Website Logo', 'website_logo'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_logo',
                'id'    => 'website_logo',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_logo
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Website Name', 'website_name'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_name',
                'id'    => 'website_name',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_name
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Credits -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Website Credits to', 'website_credits'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_credits',
                'id'    => 'website_credits',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_credits
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Credits Link -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Website Credits to Link', 'website_credits_link'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_credits_link',
                'id'    => 'website_credits_link',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_credits_link
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Copyright -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Copyrights', 'website_copyright'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_copyright',
                'id'    => 'website_copyright',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_copyright
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website First Ad -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Ad One', 'website_first_ad'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_first_ad',
                'id'    => 'website_first_ad',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_first_ad
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_textarea($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Second Ad -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Ad Two', 'website_second_ad'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_second_ad',
                'id'    => 'website_second_ad',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_second_ad
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_textarea($data); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Website Third Ad -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo form_label('Ad Three', 'website_third_ad'); ?>
        <?php
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'website_third_ad',
                'id'    => 'website_third_ad',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'value'     => $item->website_third_ad
            );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_textarea($data); ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Update Website', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

On click of the button you can bind the ajax call to submit the data to the update action of the controller and you can handle response to show relevant message on the same page.

**Sample ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'settings/update',//controller action
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'JSON',
    data:{'data':data,'id':id},//form data you need to upate with the id
    success:function(response) {
       //show success message here
    },
    error:function(response) {
       //show error message here
    }   
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the data is posted thru the controller. then use set_value to your input fields to retain the values after submit

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public function index(){

        if($this->input->post()){
            //set rules for form validation
            if($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE){
                //then update
            }
        }

        //your views, data or any other things you do
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
     echo form_input('name', set_value('name'));
```